# Apple ID working for iPhone but not for iPad

Tags: ipad, apple-id

I have an Apple ID and password that has been working fine with my iPhone. I have been able to buy music and download apps with no problems. I bought an iPad and configured it with the same email. I have tried to buy music and download apps using the iPad with the same Apple ID and password but have been unable to connect with the server.

Do I need a special configuration for the Apple ID in order to be able to use it from different devices?

Comment: No - one Apple ID is able to be used on many devices (more than most have fingers and toes) if all you want to do is download paid apps. Music is restricted to 10 devices in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

One Apple ID can be used with multiple devices and if you are hitting a limit that too many devices are using it for a specific use (say playing purchased music on too many devices - no slots are left to authorize), you should get an error message.

The likely culprit is a network or other device specific error, but you may have to troubleshoot this:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4895

Most of the authorization issues can be solved starting with the above guide and general troubleshooting might be to check that you can browse the iTunes store and ask the networking staff to make sure things aren't being blocked or take the device to another public internet to be sure it's not a problem with the network and not the device.